# Удаление SQL Managment Studio 2014 вручную

Tags: sql-server

**Предыстория:** 
Дело в том, что недавно я ставил Team Foundation Server, который потребовал обновления моего MS SQL Server 2014 до 2016 версии, что привело к некорректному прерыванию обновления(так как у меня windows 7, а 2016 сервер требует windows 8). Дальше поступил опрометчиво, попытавшись удалить обычным способом SQL Server 2014(чтобы установить заново), что опять привело к ошибкам и некорректному завершению удаления, в итоге пришлось качать Uninstall tool 3.5.2, чтобы удалить его(соответственно он удалил его из реестра, но не полностью, незнаю почему). Но после этого хода, я смог установить уже другой обьект сервера, стал он отлично, но!
**Приоритетная задача\вопрос:**
Management Studio 2014 перестала запускаться. После двойного клика по SSMS.exe вообще ни ошибки, ни отклику нету, ни процесса не висит. Честно говоря я даже незнаю как это загуглить. Дело в том, что я не могу удалить среду обычным путем(в панели управленя->удаление программ отсутствует возможность запустить окно "remove\repair...").
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Вот на этом скрине видно, что нету instance для запуска нужного окна удаления компонентов

Так вот основной вопрос. Как я могу запустить это окно удаления компонентов MS SQL Server 2014, чтобы удалить среду, или же есть ли возможность удалить его вручную?

Честно говоря, я такой себе геморой сделал из-за своей глупости, что легче уже снести и поставить os, но хотел бы исправить проблему, а не полностью сносить систему ради этого.

Comment: дак вместе с объектом сервера вы не ставили SSMS заново то?